# CSS Animation does not work on CodePen or anywhere but on JSFiddle

Tags: css

The code below animates on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpahadi/h7SYp/1163/). But not with my webpages and [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxaNKg). Wondering what's being missed:

```
<div class="marquee-container">
<p class="marquee">
    <img src="http://baikalpiksamuha.com/images/uploads/image_594305088943_132137736353.jpg" />
    <img src="http://baikalpiksamuha.com/images/uploads/image_1183525799947_1406772043415.jpg" />
    <img src="http://baikalpiksamuha.com/images/uploads/image_2335497987849_2163563643106.jpg" />
    <img src="http://baikalpiksamuha.com/images/uploads/image_1183525799947_1406772043415.jpg" />
    <img src="http://baikalpiksamuha.com/images/uploads/image_594305088943_132137736353.jpg" />
</p>
```

And the style:

```
.marquee-container{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.marquee {
    background:#e4e4e4;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: mar 30s linear infinite;
}

.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.marquee img{
    width:300px
}

/* Make it move! */
@keyframes mar {
    0%   { top:   0 }
    40%  { top: -100% }
    50%  { top: -100% }
    90%  { top: 0% }
    100% { top: 0% }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the jsfiddle example you provided, you are including a script called [prefixfree.js](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/prefixfree.js) which adds cross browser vendor prefixes. Since the animations aren't working for you, I assume you are currently using a browser that requires prefixed animation properties. It's worth pointing out that the animation works fine in Firefox (without the script).

If you add the `-webkit` vendor prefix, it should work as expected. Add additional prefixes for additional support.

[**Updated CodePen Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LErxxG)

```css
.marquee-container{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.marquee {
    background: #e4e4e4;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-animation: mar 30s linear infinite;
    animation: mar 30s linear infinite;
}

.marquee:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.marquee img {
    width:300px
}

@-webkit-keyframes mar {
    0%   { top: 0 }
    40%  { top: -100% }
    50%  { top: -100% }
    90%  { top: 0% }
    100% { top: 0% }
}

@keyframes mar {
    0%   { top: 0 }
    40%  { top: -100% }
    50%  { top: -100% }
    90%  { top: 0% }
    100% { top: 0% }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee-container">
    <p class="marquee">
        <img src="http://baikalpiksamuha.com/images/uploads/image_594305088943_132137736353.jpg" />
        <img src="http://baikalpiksamuha.com/images/uploads/image_1183525799947_1406772043415.jpg" />
        <img src="http://baikalpiksamuha.com/images/uploads/image_2335497987849_2163563643106.jpg" />
        <img src="http://baikalpiksamuha.com/images/uploads/image_1183525799947_1406772043415.jpg" />
        <img src="http://baikalpiksamuha.com/images/uploads/image_594305088943_132137736353.jpg" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you can also set [autoprefixer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bRoW2.png) in the CSS settings on CodePen as well.